# Convert CSV or TAB File Having 1.44 Million Lines to EXCEL Format Given EXCEL Limit

Tags: excel, csv, line, limit

This CSV or TAB file (generated by Notepad++) has 1.44 million lines but only 5 fields per line. I cannot pull the whole file into Excel due to Excel "line limit". Is there a way to convert a CSV or TAB file into an Excel format? I can split the file in Notepad++ and Excel can convert the two pieces separately but Excel cannot put the pieces back together again for export and upload.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` script. That folds 2 CSV lines into 1 line. Therefore reducing the number of lines by half.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS = ","}
NR % 2 == 1 {prevLine = $0}
NR % 2 == 0 {print prevLine FS $0}
END {if (NR % 2 == 1) print}
```

#### input.csv

```
10,11,12,13,14,15
20,21,22,23,24,25
30,31,32,33,34,35
40,41,42,43,44,45
50,51,52,53,54,55
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.csv
```

#### output:

```
10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25
30,31,32,33,34,35,40,41,42,43,44,45
50,51,52,53,54,55
```

#### explanation:

```
BEGIN { # preprocessing
    FS = ","; # define field separator to ","
}
NR % 2 == 1 { # for every even number input line
    prevLine = $0; # store the current line in variable prevLine
} 
NR % 2 == 0 { # for every odd number input line
    print prevLine FS $0; # print the pervious line, appened with "," and current line
}
END { # post processing
    if (NR % 2 == 1) { # if last line is odd number input line
        print; # print the last line as well.
    }
}
```